# Unable to import sample project from sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I want to study the sample code in android sdk which is cubelivewallpaper..
So i decided to import it. But it has a problem. i am not able to click finish because it is disabled.. here:

[image]

and here is i am trying to import. 
[image]

Anyone can help me how to import sdk project wihout getting this error?

Thank you..

Comment: Look at this . http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/importing-existing-source-code-into-eclipse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That project exists in the sample projects.(CubeLiveWallpaper)

Try Creating a sample project. No need to import it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. i saw the projects.. :)

Answer (score 4):

To import sample project follow the following steps:

- Click on `File ---> New ---> other`, new project wizard will be opened.
- Now under android option click on the `"android sample project"` and press next.
- Select the build target e.g. android 4.1 and press next.
- Now you will get list of sample projects available. Select the one you want say "CubeLiveWallpaper" and press finish. You are done

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't import but Create New project from exists derictory and choose this project. Good luck!

Comment: hmm.. the dialog of import and create new project from existing dir are the same.. I am using eclipse juno for mobile devs.

Comment: Just your project include src, res and minifest but .proj, .classpath and other not. It reason why you need to create new project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the SDK examples aren't Eclipse projects so you can't use the Import function. Whenever I've wanted to try any of the samples, I've created the project manually in Eclipse, and then just copied the contents (res, src and AndroidManifest.xml) from the SDK folder into the new Eclipse project.